# SortedList that just takes IComparable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, icomparable

I have an interface `IScriptItem` that implements `IComparable<IQueueItem>`.
In my eyes it would seem enough to have `IComparable` items in order to have a sorted anything. But all I can find is Dictionaries, Hashtables and SortedLists that are actually SortedTrees.

What I'm looking for is a sorted generic list that takes IComparables.
Am I looking in the wrong places?

Comment: You haven't really said what you're looking for - I'm guessing a generic list which keeps its items in order?

Comment: Sorry, it was late, I was getting a bit fed up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing built-in. You have some options:

- Use SortedList with a dummy TValue.
- Use a list or array and call List.Sort() or Array.Sort() when necessary.
- Write your own.
- Use a third party library

For this particular case check out Wintellect PowerCollections OrderedBag class, which uses a red-black tree internally. Other good free data structure libraries include NGenerics and C5.

Comment: Am I the only one that thinks it's weird that such a basic thing doesn't exist?

Comment: I think the number and variety of built-in data structures is shockingly poor, yes.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want an SortedCollection< TValue> instead of the various SortedCollection< TKey, TValue> that are there.

In .NET 4 there is a new [`SortedSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) class that keeps its items in order, but doesn't allow duplicates. Otherwise you'll have to look at 3rd party options, like the one Matt Howells mentions.