# Sorting a list based on one its item and  on custom condition

Tags: c#, list, sorting, element

I've a list which contains a string and another list in it - sample code as follows:

```
List<Config> ConfigLists;
```

Here ***Config*** is a class containing 2 members:

- String Name
- List BinaryLists

where ***Binary*** is another class.

I want to sort 'ConfigLists' list based on 'Name' contained in each list item.

Can anyone please guide?

Also I would like to use a substring of 'Name' for sorting as the 'Name' would contain values like "Week 07", "Week 09" etc where the substring I will take for comaparision is the numeric part of string (e.g. '07', '09' etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linq should help here;

```
// using System.Linq;
ConfigLists = ConfigLists.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

...which of course can be used to sort by a substring...

```
// Skips "Week ";
// using System.Linq;
ConfigLists = ConfigLists.OrderBy(x => x.Name.Substring(5)).ToList();
```

If you have a more complex sort order or want to avoid temporary strings in your sorting, you may want to instead use an IComparer to do the sorting for you;

```
class WeekComparer : IComparer<Config>
{
    public int Compare(Config x, Config y)
    { 
        return string.Compare(x.Name, 5, y.Name, 5, int.MaxValue); 
    }
}

// using System.Linq;
var weekComparer = new WeekComparer();
ConfigLists = ConfigLists.OrderBy(x => x, weekComparer).ToList();
```

The IComparer also works with "plain old" Sort if you don't like Linq's syntax.

```
var weekComparer = new WeekComparer();
ConfigLists.Sort(weekComparer);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just pass a delegate to the Sort() member-function like this:

```
List<Config> ConfigLists; 
//...
ConfigLists.Sort((c1,c2) => 
    int.Parse(c1.Name.Substring(5)) - int.Parse(c2.Name.Substring(5)));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you implement the [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) interface, you can decide exactly how your custom objects get sorted.

returning a positive int (e.g. 1) will stack ahead and returning a negative int (e.g. -1) will stack behind.

**EDIT:**

The code could look like:

```
public class Config : IComparable
{
   public string Name { get; set; }

   // other properties

   public int CompareTo(object obj) {
        if (obj == null) return 1;

        Config otherConfig = obj as Config;
        if (otherConfig != null) 

            // this is where you would place the compare logic

        else
           throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a Config");
    }
}
```

With this sort of solution, you will have to call list.Sort() at some point.  If you are after efficiency you might want to keep the collection in order as you go (spreading the time to sort).  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100615/sortedlist-that-just-takes-icomparablet) explains options to do that.

Comment: Could you pls give examples similar to mine? that would be great.
My question was also like how to use Icomparable and Comparer things in C# efficiently?